# How to make a button change on mouseover in html

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

I am new to using javascript in HTML and I want to make a simple on mouseover script that changes the image on a button. All I need is a javascript code that will fit between 2 script tags and a HTML code that references to the code between the script tags.

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use CSS.

Comment: css `:hover` [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)?

Comment: I think you will find tons of example of `mouseover` event (javascript) or `hover` (CSS) in your favourite web search engine

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask - HINT: Post effort and code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CSS and not JavaScript. Using JavaScript would be ugly and waste of time. Using CSS its fast and easy. This could be a small CSS code of what you require.

```
.image-btn {
    background-image: url("button-image-name.jpg");
}

.image-btn:hover {
    background-image: url("button-image-name-on-hover.jpg");
}
```